# How to create pdf from downloaded photos (python)

Tags: python, pdf, download

**I want to create pdf after downloading photos,it's not save pdf file. Where have error?
**

```
from fpdf import FPDF
import random
import urllib.request


for i in range(1,10):
 def image(url):
  name=random.randrange(1,80)
  fullname=str(name)+"."+"jpg"
  a=urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,'/Users/Dato/Desktop/python/photo/{}.jpg'.format(name))
  image("https://img.yumpu.com/54761731/{}/950x950/7uhbctpd0.jpg".format(random.randrange(1, 80)))

  pdf = FPDF()
  pdf.add_page()
  pdf.image('{}'.format(a), x=0, y=0)
  pdf.output("1.pdf",)
```

Comment: What error? If you are getting an error message, please post it in your question.

Comment: Do not write a mistake. I want how to save this pdf

Comment: It just writes Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't do much. Here's what happens when your code runs:

```
from fpdf import FPDF
import random
import urllib.request


for i in range(1,10):
```

Here you import your packages and then you start a `for` loop. The code in the loop will be run once for each loop, and will have access to variable `i` which will change each time the loop runs.

```
def image(url):
    ...
```

The rest of your code consists of a function definition inside a `for` loop. The function you define can be called `image("example.com")` but you never do this. So the `for` loop runs and defines a function many times but never calls it. The function never runs.

Edit: to actually run the code, you could just delete the function definition and supply the URLs directly. The code would run if it wasn't in a function definition.

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

With the `def` statement, you are defining a function. It is just *building* the structure of what that particular piece of code should do. It is not actually executing it.

With the `def` inside the `for` loop, you are building the struture again and again, but never actually executing that piece of code.

If you'd insist on using functions, you can define the function outside the loop (once), and then call it using `function_name()` inside the `for` loop.

Or, you can eliminate the use of function altogehter, and simply remove the def portion nside the loop, and let the instructions be executed directly.

I had a very similar project way back which made use of similar pdf concepts. If some issue still exists, I hope it can guide you further: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/bye-nary/Python-Beginners/blob/master/ArchieComic/archie.py).